# Kendo UI Model validation only working on local environment

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI with ASP.NET MVC 3. We have one page where we use the MVC wrapper for a Kendo grid, bound to model classes annotated with validation requirements.

Everything works fine when deployed locally, but when deployed on our test server the validation doesn't work. After closer inspection I saw that the resulting javascript produced by the Kendo MVC wrapper for the column definitions has different values for the "editor" field for each column.

The value of the "editor" field when run on our test server is missing the data-val attributes for the input element.

What causes could there be for this difference in output? We have double checked and it is the same source being used for both deployments. Also everything else works normally on the test environment.

This is the value for the "editor" field on one of the columns when deployed locally:

```
"editor":"\u003cinput class=\"text-box single-line\" data-val=\"true\" data-val-regex=\"Invalid Platform Name!\" data-val-regex-pattern=\"^[a-z A-Z]+$\" data-val-required=\"The PlatformName field is required.\" id=\"PlatformName\" name=\"PlatformName\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"field-validation-valid\" data-valmsg-for=\"PlatformName\" data-valmsg-replace=\"true\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e"
```

And this is what is generated for the same column on the test server:

```
"editor":"\u003cinput class=\"text-box single-line\" id=\"PlatformName\" name=\"PlatformName\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"field-validation-valid\" id=\"PlatformName_validationMessage\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e"
```

Model:

```
public class PlatformModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-z A-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Platform Name!")]
    [CustomValidation(typeof(ApproverGroupValidator), "IsEntryNull")]
    public string PlatformName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AclGroup { get; set; }
    [Editable(false)]
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

MVC Wrapper:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PlatformModel>().Name("ManagePlatformGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden();
                columns.Template(@<img />).ClientTemplate("# if(!IsDefault) { #<div class='btnGridDelete' onclick=\"deleteRow(this, 'ManagePlatformGrid', 'Platform', 'DeletePopoutPF')\"><span>X</span></div># } #")
                    .Width(30)
                    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "border-left-width:0px;border-right-width:0px;" })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "border-left-width:0px;" });
                columns.Bound(c => c.PlatformName).Title("Platform Name")
                    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "border-left-width:0px;" })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "border-left-width:0px;text-align:right;" })
                    .Width(160);
                columns.Bound(c => c.AclGroup).Title("ACL Group");
            })
            .Sortable()
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom))
            .Events(events => events.DataBound("PlatformBound"))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Batch(true)
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetPlatform", "ApproverGroupTeam"))
                    .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
                    .Create(create => create.Action("CreatePlatform", "ApproverGroupTeam"))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("UpdatePlatform", "ApproverGroupTeam"))
                    .Destroy(create => create.Action("DeletePlatform", "ApproverGroupTeam"))
                    .Events(events => events.Error("PlatformHaveErrors"))
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we were using Web.config transforms and were missing the two lines:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

in our Web.TEST.config file, so even though they were present in the main Web.config file the appSettings section was being replaced by the section which was missing these settings in our test environment.